# Using a select query to source values from joined tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to source a value in a form from the table in the code below 'tblJobTitles'.  The value I would like to source is the value 'JobTitle' Unfortunately, in the control box i keep getting #Name? error. I am trying to adust the properties but everthing i try gives me the same error.

Note: if i attempt to do this without joining 'tblContacts' to 'tblJobTitles' and using only 'tblContacts', I can successfully retrieve the job title in the field on the form, only that it returns the numerical unique ID number from the job title table.  Is it possible to reformat it to return the text value?

```
sql_get = "SELECT tblContacts.*, tblJobTitles.* FROM tblJobTitles INNER JOIN (tblContacts INNER JOIN tblTeams ON tblContacts.Team = tblTeams.ID) ON tblJobTitles.ID = tblContacts.JobTitle WHERE [tblTeams].[team]= '" & cboDepartments.Value & "'"
Me.frmstaticdatadepartments08.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```

Comment: Do us a favor, after `sql_get`, write `Debug.Print sql_get`. Put a breakpoint on that line. Let us know what it prints out

Comment: you want me to put Debug.Print slq_get AFTER the line 'Me.frmstaticdatadepartments08.form.recordsource = sql_get' ?

Comment: No, before please. Between `sql_get` and for form record source assignment

Comment: SELECT tblContacts.*, tblJobTitles.* FROM tblJobTitles INNER JOIN (tblContacts INNER JOIN tblTeams ON tblContacts.Team = tblTeams.ID) ON tblJobTitles.ID = tblContacts.JobTitle WHERE [tblTeams].[team]= 'Milan Tax Services'

Comment: (i entered it between line one and line two.. The above is the result

Comment: Hm, okay. Right click on your control box and go to properties. What's the control source for it (On the Data tab)?

Comment: the data source is 'JobTitle'

Comment: Is the name of the control also `JobTitle` ? If so, change it to something else. And if there's another control with the name `JobTitle` change those as well.

Comment: I have renamed the control and now no controls on the form exist named 'jobtitle' however it still retrieves the same value

Comment: Delete the control, set the source to `JobTitle` and name it `Job_test` or something. Let's see what that gives us

Comment: For your information, all works fine when i change my query to this:   sql_get = "SELECT tblContacts.CompleteName, tblContacts.CurrentPosition, tblContacts.Level, tblContacts.ContractType, tblContacts.ID, tblContacts.Foto, tblTeams.Team, tblJobTitles.JobTitle FROM tblJobTitles INNER JOIN (tblContacts INNER JOIN tblTeams ON tblContacts.Team = tblTeams.ID) ON tblJobTitles.ID = tblContacts.JobTitle WHERE [tblTeams].[team]= '" & cboDepartments.Value & "'"
Me.frmstaticdatadepartments08.Form.RecordSource = sql_get

Comment: But this is not my preferred methodology.  I am wondering if the duplicate ID fields in the tables is causing this issue.

Comment: So, the `#Name` error means there's a circular reference. That means that either a control shares the same name/control source, or maybe `tblContacts` also has a `JobTitle` field, or something. When you identify every field in the query, you're being very explicit and Access knows which field you're talking about. (you shouldn't use `*` anyway, they're slower).

Comment: Ah ok..  one clarification..  In tblContacts there is a field called 'JobTitle' which pulls it's value from the 'JobTitle' field in the table 'tblJobTitles'.. (One to many relationship)...      I thought that was clear for you..  sorry about that..  PS- thanks for the tip on the *

Comment: That is your problem then. What you can do is select the fields like you've done, and give them aliases. `tblContacts.JobTitle AS ContactsJobTitle, tblJobTitle.JobTitle AS [Job_Title]` or something. The fact that there's 2 similar fields and you're simply selecting all (`*`), it's confusing Access.

Comment: @Animate. Thanks for all your patience. Now i understand that topic better.  If you post that answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#Name` error can have a couple different sources. This means Access can't delineate a field or property because :

1. It shares a name with *something*, whether that be a control name
   and a control source, etc.
2. It can't find the field you're referring to (such as in this scenario)

So, in your query, you're saying, "Give me everything from these 2 tables."

When you have 2 identical fields and you run the query and view the results, Access will pre-pend the table name to the field. (`tblContact.JobTitle`, and `tblJobTitle.JobTitle`). This is because it recognizes you have overlapping (identical) field names in both tables, so it needs to identify them as unique values. You probably could have gotten away with adding the table name in front of your control source, but it's better to be explicit where you can be.

When you were referencing the field `JobTitle` in your control, Access was wondering which field you were referring to, because `JobTitle` is in *both* of your tables. This is a reason some people uses aliases e.g: `tblContact.JobTitle AS ContactJobTitle, tblJobTitle.JobTitle AS [Job_Title]`. This let's you be very explicit and tell Access exactly which field you're referring to.

You should be explicit when selecting fields from a query as well.

`SELECT Table.*` is known to have performance issues, and you lose the ability to adequately refer to which field you want to select from if you're use these fields in a Control (when there's overlap in the tables).

Thanks to @HansUp as well for the correction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The query returned one field named `tblContact.JobTitle` and another field named `tblJobTitle.JobTitle`.  His Control Source asked for a field named `JobTitle`.  As far as Access was concerned the query result set did not include a field named just `JobTitle`, hence name error.  It's not a circular reference problem.

Comment: @HansUp I thought that made it a circular reference error, because Access can't determine which `JobTitle` he was referring to? I do understand exactly what you're saying though and can see how my words could not make sense in this scenario

Comment: Circular is different.  `SELECT fld1 & fld2 AS fld1` would probably trigger a circular reference error.  The `#Name` error is simply because the query does not include a field named `JobTitle`.  He would get the same error if he changed the Control Source to look for `BOGUS`.  Nothing circular about it.